# How to have a multiple entry for UK Visa

Tags: visas, uk, tourist-visas, filipino-citizens

Do I need to say that I want a multiple entry visa for the UK? (Tourist visa for 6 months) Or they will automatically put multiple on the visa? 
If it's not automatic, where should I indicate my request for "multiple entry" in the cover letter?

Comment: What country’s passport do you hold?

Comment: @RoboKaren Philippines

Comment: UK standard visitor visas are typically multiple entry and valid for 6 months. However, that does not necessarily mean that you will be allowed to enter more than once. If you intend to make repeated visits within the standard 6 month validity period you should state the expected visit dates in your application; if you’re not certain of all the dates you should explain your intentions eg how many times you plan to enter and how long each visit will be.

Comment: @Traveller That’s not true for UK entry clearance. UK visas, unlike many other countries, grant the holder an almost guaranteed entry provided that there has been no proved deception and the holder’s circumstances have not change. Also, you only have to only mention details of the forthcoming visit for visitor visas, be it a 6 month or a 10 year visa.

Comment: @greatone My point is that a visa holder must satisfy the IO on each visit that they will not live in the UK for extended periods through frequent or successive visits, or make the UK their main home. Therefore a chance of denial of entry exists each time re-entry is sought; if someone knows in advance that they will be making repeated visits during the 6 month validity period they can disclose that upfront eg in the ‘Other information’ section at the end of the application or in a covering letter

Comment: @Traveller any source for your claim that holders of entry clearance need to satisfy the IO about this?